# Powering a pump depending on the state of another pump

Tags: power-supply, mains

I have a system that tests a product's water tightness by using a pump to remove all the air.
When it reaches a certain value it turns off to test the product.

I have just bought another pump that I want to integrate into the system so that when the first pump is on, the second also turns on and when the first pump is off the second turns off. The first pump is linked to a controller which determines the on/off state. But the second pump has to be plugged into mains power and I am unsure how to link the two.

I have mainly worked with smaller, low power elements with an arduino so I am unsure how to go ahead.

Comment: hi! Welcome here. That's good context you're giving here! (I do have a few questions, though.) It *really* helps if you can think of a single, precise question. "how to get started?" is a bit broad for an authorative answer :)

Comment: questions: "when it reaches a certain value": When *what* reaches a value for *what* as observed by *what*?

Comment: "first pump is linked to a controller", "second pump…" : need datasheet or at least types of all three elements.

Comment: How small are your pumps, comparing to this one? https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32693407160.html.

Comment: Please draw a block diagram of what you have and how it’s connected, and we’ll help you from there.

Comment: Or are you using two pumps, one water, another air, like this one? https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005002918874549.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.70716ea8dCgeJ2&algo_pvid=2dc860b6-edbc-45d3-8995-dfa216982191&aem_p4p_detail=202201130219441536799111287180005767527&algo_exp_id=2dc860b6-edbc-45d3-8995-dfa216982191-1

Comment: Or do you actually need another Hall effect water/air flow sensor, like this? https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4001141423776.html

Comment: And do you need a solenoid valve to turn on/off the pump, like this: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32961862235.html

Comment: The water pump/flow sensors/solenoid valve examples above are for reference and comparison, and all have a standard diameter of half inch. How large is you pump's diameter, quarter inch, half inch or half foot?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. The air pump that is connected directly to the controller is 4m³/h and the new one is 16m³/h. The controller reads the pressure inside the product and when the ideal pressure is reached, the pump is turned off. The new pump has been purchased to make the process quicker.

Comment: Can we have links to your pumps and pressure sensor?

Comment: Unless you're married to the idea of building this yourself, yo could just buy an [Automatic Vacuum Switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=automatic+vacuum+switch&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US906&sxsrf=AOaemvKLrnpDcxuFOLau_2Hn-kAooCtyJA%3A1642078048179&ei=YB_gYdOdCrKq_QbZkbbYCg&oq=automated+vacuum+control+switch&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0COgcIABBHELADOgcIIxCwAhAnOggIABAIEAcQHjoGCAAQDRAeOggIABANEAUQHjoICAAQCBANEB46BQgAEIYDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgASgUIRBjyB0oFCEQYmyNKBAhDGANQvQ1Y5BpgxD9oAXACeACAAYMBiAH7BZIBAzkuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz).

Answer (score 1):

The wire to the first pump (the MCU-controlled one) can be observed with a Hall sensor, and that could trigger a relay turning on/off the second pump (High-voltage one).

There's a diagram in the [UGN5303](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/40880.pdf) datasheet for such usage of Hall sensors (current monitor).

Or better than that, if the systems are not isolated, both pumps could be switched by the MCU at the same time (of course through MOSFETs/relays/SSR/etc. depending on motor requirements).